# compiling google calendar API - iOS in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, api, google-calendar-api

Hi guys so I followed the Google calendar API guide on 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift
however when I tried compiling and it gave me the error: multiple methods named 'initWithArray' found in the GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib file.

[image]

I don't know how to fix it.. please help!

Comment: Can you please provide us with your code? example of what you have done

Comment: ok. I just added the screenshot of the error. what exactly should I show you?

Comment: Why are you tagging swift if this is Objective-C?

Comment: The API guide for swift asks us to add this file in the supporting files and then crate a bridging header, probably so that the code can use both languages. This is in step 3 part f,g,h of the guide. I haven't made any changes to the file

Comment: You mean bridge-header.h correct? Please provide the swift code you try to write after setting up the bridge.